# htop displays identical program in multiple lines

Tags: process, htop

When I use htop, I found that an identical program occupies multiple lines:
[image: screenshot]

Additionally the PID could not be traced:

```
me@host:~$ ps 16255 16256 16259 24772 16254
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
```

How could such an obscure happening?

Comment: These look like multiple threads of the same process. Normal behavior for multi-threaded applications.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The duplicated lines are [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) of a single [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). You can recognize them by the different color in the command column (if you have configured that in **Setup > Display options > Display threads in a different color**) and by having the same amount of memory reported since memory is shared among threads of the same process.

If you don’t want to see threads of applications in `htop`, use **Setup > Display Options > Hide userland process threads**.

See also:

- [htop showing duplicate applications with very odd bizarre results upwards of 20,30,40 or more, see screen grab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312419/htop-showing-duplicate-applications-with-very-odd-bizarre-results-upwards-of-20)

Comment: Confirmed. Press SHIFT + h to toggle "display threads" or "hide threads".